# mysql Conditionally apply multiply factor in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, case

I have a simple table with high low values for the day, as well as the last observed value.

I would like to query the table and return the last value, but only if its within a certain percentage of the high or low.  Also, I'd like that percentage to adjust based on the range (or diff) between high-low for that day.

So, for example, Say I have the following:

| Date | High | Low | Last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 90 | 10 | 30 |
| 2021-01-02 | 90 | 10 | 15 |
| 2021-01-03 | 90 | 10 | 90 |
| 2021-01-04 | 20 | 10 | 12 |
| 2021-01-05 | 20 | 10 | 18 |

And I want to calculate a target based on the high-low range so I can return the last values when they are within 10% of the difference between a large range, like 90-10 = 80, so within 8.  So return any Last value that is >=82, or <= 18

And for a small range, like 20 - 10 =10, I want to return Last values that are within 20% or 25%.

So I imagine I will need to use a case statement to set the multiplier based on range diff, and then perform the (high - low), and then multiply the diff by the multiplier from the case statement, and then determine if the last is less than low + target or greater than high - target.

But I don't know how to construct that query, if it requires both case statements and sub selects, or an inner join?

Comment: Please share your desired output.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: mysql currently 5.6 but planning to upgrade to 8.0 soonish.

Comment: From the above table, desired output would return 4 records, all but the row where Last value = 30.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE CASE WHEN ((High - Low) >= 50) 
    THEN Last <= Low + ((High - Low) * 0.1) OR Last >= High - ((High - Low) * 0.1)
    ELSE Last <= Low + ((High - Low) * 0.25) OR Last >= High - ((High - Low) * 0.25) 
    END;
```

I don't know how you distinguished small ranges from big ranges, I used (High - Low) >= 50 for big ranges, and (High - Low) < 50 for small ranges.

Output:

| Date | High | Low | Last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | 90 | 10 | 15 |
| 2021-01-03 | 90 | 10 | 90 |
| 2021-01-04 | 20 | 10 | 12 |
| 2021-01-05 | 20 | 10 | 18 |